# Inner class member/attribute visibility (C#)

Tags: c#, nested, visibility

I am looking for a visibility modifier for attributes of an inner class that would allow the outer class to modify/set a value but external classes could only get/read the value.

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {
        // I want this to be editable by Outer instances
        // but read-only to other external classes.
        public string attribute;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an access modifier for that, but you can get away with something like this:

```
public class Outer
{
    private static Action<Inner, string> InnerAttributeSetter;

    public class Inner
    {
        static Inner()
        {
            Outer.InnerAttributeSetter = (inner, att) => inner.Attribute = att;
        }

        public string Attribute { get; private set; }
    }

    public Outer()
    {
        var inner = new Inner();

        InnerAttributeSetter(inner, "Value");

        Console.WriteLine(inner.Attribute);
    }
}
```

Basically you taking advantage of the fact that nested classes have access to `private` members of the enclosing class and providing for the enclosing class a proxy to set the `attribute` property for a given `Inner` instance. Since external classes do not have access to this proxy you satisfied your requirement.

Comment: How about having a private inner class that extends the public inner class and have properties on the private class that actually set the properties of the public class?

Comment: In terms of hacks I would prefer the delegate based approach and would not mix inheritance, but if it works, the final choice is yours.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with attributes of other data types? Your example is for strings only.

Comment: Yes, expose a delegate with the correct type `Action<Inner, TYourType>`.

Comment: Would that work for primitive types? If not could I pass in another private object that contained my double/string values?

Comment: The approach works for any type, you just need to create the delegates with the type you want to use.

Comment: I get the error: Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires '1' type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Since Inner class member/atribute is not static, you cannot hold or modify the state of that member.

I think the example of John Angelo comes the closest you can get.